# How to define template engine in FOSUserBundle 2.0?

Tags: php, twig, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.7

I just moved from FOS User Bundle 2.0 alpha1 to the stable 2.0, and I get this.

With this configuration:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: BizTV\UserBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
    template:
        engine: twig
```

I get this error:

*Unrecognized option "template" under "fos_user"*

And with this configuration:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: BizTV\UserBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
#    template:
#        engine: twig
```

I instead get this error:

*The parameter "fos_user.template.engine" must be defined.*

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1621

Apparently the template engine is deprecated, but I was calling it in a custom line in my security controller.